# Why use XGbytes address space for a DRAM controller

Tags: byte, bit, soc

#1. Does "64GByte address space" means 64*(1024^3)*8 of different addresses?
#2. Or 64*(1024^3) different addresses and each locations is 1 byte wide.
According to the documentation that I am reading (not sharable) a 36 bits address is used (2^36=64G). Thus the expression of "64GByte address space" means #2. But why not use just "64G address space"? Is there a convention for this?